# Windows 8 XAML - make a custom back button

Tags: c#, xaml

I made a back button that is going to go with the theme of my app. Here is the code for the original back button:

```
            <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
```

How can I supplement the supplied back button with an image of my own.

Comment: What does your `BackButtonStyle` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Blend to edit the template. Once you save it in app.xaml file, you can reference it as a style everywhere in your app.

Some resources I found for using Blend for buttons.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613598.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/64937/Building-Better-Buttons-in-Expression-Blend-Silver

Or you can just wrap an image as its content then remove border.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Height="32" Width="32" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
      <Image Source="someimage.png" Height="32" Width="32"></Image>
</Button>
```